# Yii2 yii\helpers\Url helpers Url to another site

Tags: php, url, yii, yii2

I am using  `yii\helpers\Url` helpers to access my site's urls in menu. But there should be a url goes to another site, like [www.anothersite.com/action](http://example.com).

How can I place this link via `yii\helpers\Url` helpers ?

Is it possible to add a url that goes other site with yii2 `yii\helpers\Url` helpers ?

Answer (score 1):

This soultion is reusable, so give a try.

Define an alias inside application's config file.

```
Yii::setAlias('@another', 'http://anothersite.com/action');
```

Then you'll be able use it throughout entire application like,

```
//assuming you've already imported yii\helpers\Url
Url::to('@another');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, just like this:

```
<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to('http://www.anothersite.com/action') ?>
```

But this is the same as:

```
<?= 'http://www.anothersite.com/action' ?>
```

If you want to use routes there for another website (so you can use array route with action parameters for example) you need to configure first the urlManager for the other site, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: thank you for answer, I tried it a week ago but it shows `mysite.com/http://www.anothersite.com/action` . And I don't want use routes. Just going given url.

Comment: How do you invoke it?

Comment: I bet you use `Url::toRoute` or `Url::to` with array instead of string.

Comment: Hey @Bizley, I'll test it soon and inform you exact result. Thanks !